# Opencart new shippping module error while checkout

Tags: php, html, opencart

Warning: Shipping method required! 
When i proceed to checkout with a new shipping module.
[image: warning only in my new module]

My model code is given below:

```
if ($status) {
    $quote_data = array();

    $quote_data['ndz.ndz'] = array(
        'code'         => 'ndz',
        'title'        => $this->config->get('ndz_name'),
        'cost'         => $this->config->get('ndz_amount'),
    'text'         => $this->currency->format($this->config->get('ndz_amount'))
    );

    $method_data = array(
        'code'       => 'ndz',
        'title'      => $this->language->get('text_title'),
        'quote'      => $quote_data,
    'sort_order' => $this->config->get('ndz_sort_order'),
    'name' => $this->config->get('ndz_name'),
    'amount' => $this->config->get('ndz_amount'),
        'error'      => false
    );
}

return $method_data;
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your

```
$quote_data['ndz.ndz'] = array(
    'code'         => 'ndz',
```

to

```
$quote_data['ndz'] = array(
    'code'         => 'ndz.ndz',
```